# To check the number of hits to the URL mapped by Route 53 Alias record to ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-route53

I was wondering if there is any provision or service provided by aws to check the traffic flowing to the URL.

MY domain is hosted by Hostgater and mapped to ELB with route 53 using a alias name.

I know dig  will give me an similar result.

But i was wondering if AWS has service that something similar to like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get request tracing enabled on your ELB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html